# How to determine Gurobi or solver version in JuMP

Tags: julia, version, gurobi, julia-jump

In Python, you can do:

```
print(gurobipy.gurobi.version())
```

What is the equivalent for Julia and JuMP?

I tried

```
using Gurobi
Gurobi.version()
```

Without success. I am not trying to get `Gurobi.jl` package version which can be obtained with `] status Gurobi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@przemyslaw-szufel's answer is mostly correct, but it can be wrong with the minor version. The constants he refers to are actually the ones we copy from the `gurobi.h` file, not from the Gurobi library itself, so you might get `v9.5.0` returned when the actual library is `v9.5.1`.

You can get the exact version using:

```
julia> using Gurobi

julia> const MOI = Gurobi.MOI
MathOptInterface

julia> v = MOI.get(Gurobi.Optimizer(), MOI.SolverVersion())
"9.1.0"

julia> VersionNumber(v)
v"9.1.0"
```

this is mostly solver-independent, although not all packages support `MOI.SolverVersion`.

Answer (score 2):

There are three integer variables for this you need to combine them to get the full version number:

```
julia> println("Grurobi version: $(Gurobi.GRB_VERSION_MAJOR).$(Gurobi.GRB_VERSION_MINOR).$(Gurobi.GRB_VERSION_TECHNICAL)")
Grurobi version: 9.5.0
```

Comment: Thank you!
Maybe there could be a simple function in JuMP like `JuMP.solverversion()` that would output this simple info?

Comment: JuMP is independent of the solver. You can have one JuMP and to `Model`s with different solvers. On the other hand Gurobi.jl exposes whatever Gurobi has in its C programming interface. Have also a look at https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl/blob/master/src/gen95/libgrb_common.jl